# About maxima and minima of a two-variable function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

> Discuss maxima/minima of the following function:
>   $$f(x,y)=2(x^4+y^4+1)-(x+y)^2$$

It's easy to compute the gradient and the hessian of the function:
$$\nabla(f)=(8x^3-2(x+y),8y^3-2(x+y)) \qquad H(f)=\begin{bmatrix}24x^2-2 & -2 \\ -2 & 24y^2-2\end{bmatrix}$$
from which we can easily see that $\nabla(f)=0 \iff (x,y)\in\{(0,0),(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2},\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt2})\}$ and by studing the hessian, we can understand that $f$ has a minima in $P_{1/2}(\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2},\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$.

The real problem is to discuss what happens in $(0,0)$. Clearly we have that $f(0,0)=2$ but the second derivative test fails as the determinant of $H(f)(0,0)$ is $0$. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Taylor's formula and study the sign of the higher order differentials. However, it is easier to study directly what happens around $(0,0)$.

If you restrict yourself to the sets $B_m=\{(x,y): y=mx\}$ and study the function $\phi_m(x) = f(x,mx)=2(1+m^4)x^4+2-(1+m)^2x^2$, you can observe that,

$$
\phi'(0) = 0, \quad \phi''(0) = -2(1+m)^2\leq 0.
$$

So, if $m \ne 1$, $\phi_m$ attains a maximum at $x=0$.

If $m=-1$, 
$$\phi_{-1}''(0)=0, \phi_{-1}'''(0) = 0, \phi_{-1}^{(4)}(0) = 96 > 0,$$ which means that $\phi_{-1}$ attains a minimum at $x_0$.

Considering these two facts, in every neighbouhood of $(0,0)$ there are points $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)>f(0,0)$ (the ones in $B_{-1}$) and points $(x,y)$ for which $f(x,y)<f(0,0)$ (for instance the ones in $B_1$). The conclusion is that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I actually thought about using Taylor's formula but it would have been more complicated. May I ask you how you decide which direction to follow to find that a determined point is a saddle?

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci straight lines are a simple way to start, just like when you compute directional limits. In this case, once you write down $f(x,mx)$, you can classify the stationary point using 1D Taylor's formula. I simply picked two directions that I knew would lead to different conclusions. Be aware that this does not work when the point is actually an extreme point.

Comment: @AlbertoAndrenucci I edited my post so that the choice of $y=x$ and $y=-x$ becomes natural.

Comment: Question solved, thanks a lot. If you want, I just posted another exercise.